# Clicking a Chrome bookmark folder with Applescript

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, browser, applescript

I'm trying to use an applescript that uses UI to click a bookmark folder I have in Google Chrome called "WatchADay", and click the Open All Tabs in New Window button inside that folder. Here is what I've tried.

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        --click menu item "Open All Bookmarks in New Window" of menu item "WatchADay" of menu "Bookmarks" of menu bar 1

        --get menu items of menu "Bookmarks" of menu bar 1
        get menu items of menu item "WatchADay" of menu "Bookmarks" of menu bar item "Bookmarks" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

This code returns {}, even though there is a bookmark in the WatchADay folder. Other codes I've tried, seemed to crash Chrome immediately.

I'm not sure how to go about this, so I was hoping you could help.

Thanks!

Also, my Chrome is 26.0.1410.65
And I'm on 10.6.8 for OS

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
activate application "Google Chrome"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        click menu item "Open All Bookmarks in New Window" of menu 1 of menu item "WatchADay" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Bookmarks" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```